# MDX -- getting tooltip (or left-hand) data to show in a query

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I would like to build a query to get the movie sales per year like this:

```
                 2014                       2015
MOVIE            SALES      SALES_IN_US     SALES       SALES_IN_US 
Avatar           $12,2039   $783            $912,2039   $783
Spider-man       $18,293    $11             $188,293    $11
Titanic          $100,203   $372            $6100,203   $372
```

How would Add in additional "properties" into either the tooltip or the second column (after MOVIE but before the measures) to show things like:

- Release Year
- Director
- Studio
- Composer

Is this called a "property" in MDX? If so, how would that be added in -- is this query-side or part of building the cube itself -- or both? How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When the Movie attribute has relationship with Release Year/Director/Studio/Composer , we could see these attributes when hover Movie in the PivotTable.

Add the relationship in  dimension editor - Attribute Relationships.

A step to step tutorial you could see here: [Dimension Properties as Tooltip in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vhinz/dimension-properties-as-tooltip-in-excel)